# `UnityEngine.LineRenderer.SetColors(UnityEngine.Color, UnityEngine.Color)' is obsolete: `Use startColor, endColor or colorGradient instead.'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-vr

[image: Game View with Play Again button on Canvas]

Receiving this error in Unity version 5.6.0b7 : Assets/GoogleVR/Scripts/UI/GvrLaserPointer.cs(83,18): warning CS0618: `UnityEngine.LineRenderer.SetColors(UnityEngine.Color, UnityEngine.Color)' is obsolete:`Use startColor, endColor or colorGradient instead.'

Can't seem to get this right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do what it tells to do:

```
 lineRenderer.SetColors(Color.white, Color.black);
```

becomes

```
lineRenderer.startColor = Color.white;
lineRenderer.endColor = Color.black
```

Same will apply to SetWidth => start/endWidth

And for the SetVertexCount => numPositions

Comment: I cannot get a build in this version and the previous one.. I'm running into a lot of errors. They say Unity 5.4.2 and Google VR 10.3 are the most stable for development. Where can I get Google VR 10.3 SDK?

Comment: This would be a different question. For your errors, look at them, they most often tell what to do or half of it already.

Comment: I'm new to Unity and programming.. After building the complete application, I got stuck at compilation and since then I've broken so many places that it is now very painful to correct them all.. So I'd rather build it again on a more stable version.. I'm using Unity 5.4.2 for that and need GoogleVR 10.3. I know there is this readme file https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk/commits/master but how do I download this specific version from here is not known to me.. Appreciate if you can help..